# AngularJS Google App Engine API Load Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-app-engine

When a Google App Engine endpoint API is called immediately once the page is loaded, the following error is thrown. I need to wait for few seconds to call the API.

Then is same when the page is reloaded by some other means, say called from an other page etc.

I have tried adding a callback to call the API after few milliseconds `$timeout(queryCallback, 100, false);` The results are the same.

Is this a AngularJS error or resource load error? How to solve the error, please share your comments.

```
angular-1.2.16.min.js:89 TypeError: Cannot read property 'queryInfo' of undefined
  at h.$scope.queryInfoAll (controllers.js:641)
  at $scope.queryInfo (controllers.js:616)
  at angular-1.2.16.min.js:119
  at e (angular-1.2.16.min.js:37)
  at angular-1.2.16.min.js:40
```

controllers.js:641

`gapi.client.database.queryInfo().execute(function (resp) {
 }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In looking at the Java endpoints example [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/blob/master/GcmEndpoints/root/src/webapp/index.html.ftl), you use endpoints in javascript by initializing via a call to

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=init"></script>
```

...which calls the JS method named "init", which is a method name of your choosing.  This is, however, a plain ole JS method that is unaware of the AngularJS lifecycle.  In your init method, it seems you explicitly init your specific endpoint library, as in:

```
gapi.client.load(apiName, apiVersion, callback, apiRoot);
```

So, in your "run()", you may have to ask if "gapi" exists and defer until it is.  You would then call "gapi.client.load()" with the callback function set.

Comment: Yes! that is the way I was also loading the client endpoints. I have modified the code to verify 'gapi' and client endpoint availability. If it is not available then I am calling 'gapi.client.load' with a callback. Thanks for the suggestion!